# i see parallel vertical black lines at the bottom when zoomed in the workspace

Tags: rendering

[image: Those blank lines at the bottom appear when i zoom.]

When in openGL and cycles as the rendering engine, i see black lines at the bottom when zoomed. I use RX 570 4gb as my gpu.

Comment: This is caused by a bug. For now you can only (1) wait for a patch to fix it (2) render with cpu (3) render with another graphics card.

Comment: ok thank you sir/mam...where can we request the blender team for a patch??

Comment: As you can see in [Brechts Comment](https://developer.blender.org/T77095#957134) the [Blender 2.9 alpha](https://builder.blender.org/download/) already has a fix implemented. I don't know how/when it will be implemented in 2.8x